# texstudio not synchro 'Go to source' in one of the chapter (or child document)

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, forward-inverse-search, pdfsync

I'm having a problem with SyncTeX. 'Go to source' (i.e. from PDF to TeX and vice versa) only in one of my chapter, but in others it is spot on. Any idea what might be going on?

NB I am compiling with `synctex=1` and I've tried deleting `*.synctex` and `*.synctex.gz` in the working directory. as well as `texstudio.ini` as suggested by others (TeXstudio 2.11.2).

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me due to an underfull \vbox at the end of my previous chapter caused by an image that slipped to the next page. After I changed the image size to fit at the top of the previous page the issue was resolved.

Comment: This may be the cause and a possible solution, but it is quite unclear if that is indeed the case (it could be something else entirely). That is not so much your fault, the original question does not provide sufficient information. But still, this answer would probably be better as a comment under the question to suggest that an underful box might have something to do with it.

Comment: That is true. But I don't have the reputation to add a comment under the question. And since this took me a while to find out, I thought it might still help someone...

Comment: This is indeed one of many possible issues impeding correct synchronization. It is hard to precisely saying causes, because it is normally a mix of thing such as floats, overfull boxes, unseen and skipped errors, watermark (my favorite culprit) and cascade of inputs. Many times a simple new compilation just solves it, therefore it is not easy to reproduce a navigation to the wrong place or total lack of navigation.